# python dictionary error when getting value from a given key

Tags: python, dictionary, rfid

I'm starting coding in Python since yesterday and I'm going without problems.
The context is a program to read an RFID card and use the readed tag to get the associated username. This will work in a embedded Linux (Debian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy))  on a Terra board. Python version is (Python 2.7.3).

I create a Dictionary an fill it with key/value pairs (both strings). When I try to get a value using one key I get an Exception that I don't understand.

```
def FindTagByNumber(self, key):
    global tags

    value = ""
    try:
        print("All dictionary: " + str(self.tags))
        print("Get name from key: " + str(key))
        value = self.tags[key]
        print("Found the name from key: " + str(value))
    except Exception as ex:
        print("Exception: " + str(ex))

    return value
```

The result is this:

```
root@ariag25:/home/python# python main.py
RFID::Initialize
RFID::Get TAG Configurations
RFID::serial port opened
All dictionary: {'4D0055AB3A': 'test1', '4D0055B6E4J': 'test2'}
Get name from key: 4D0055B6E4J
Exception: '\x024D0055B6E4J\x03'
RFID::Couldn't found the tag
```

Can someone explain what is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are still including the RFID start and end flags; the bytes with hex values 02 and 03; these are un-printable bytes so not visible when you print them directly. None of your keys in the dictionary include these bytes.

Just printing the key means you don't see those bytes, but they *are* there:

```
>>> key = '\x024D0055B6E4J\x03'
>>> print key
4D0055B6E4J
>>> key
'\x024D0055B6E4J\x03'
>>> print repr(key)
'\x024D0055B6E4J\x03'
```

The `repr()` function helps to make those bytes visual.

You could just strip those bytes:

```
key.strip('\x02\x03')
```

Demo:

```
>>> key = '\x024D0055B6E4J\x03'
>>> key.strip('\x02\x03')
'4D0055B6E4J'
>>> tags = {'4D0055AB3A': 'test1', '4D0055B6E4J': 'test2'}
>>> key in tags
False
>>> key.strip('\x02\x03') in tags
True
```

Another option would be is to add those bytes to your dictionary keys instead:

```
{'\x024D0055AB3A\x03': 'test1', '\x024D0055B6E4J\x03': 'test2'}
```

Comment: Problem solved. I already thought about that and tryied to use a regex to remove hidden chars but it didn't work probably because of bad implementation of the regex.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm new on this. I didn't know how to accept your answer. Thanks Martijn.